# Doodle-like extension for Joomla

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I'm helping a friend with his website. To schedule meetings and events they currently use a [doodle](http://doodle.com/). We've tried integrating this in their website via an iFrame. This works but in IE10 it gives a cookie warning and overall it doesn't look as good as it could.

We could simply have it open in a new page, but it would be nicer if we could integratie a doodle-like calendar in the website.

Are there any scheduling-extentions? There are many calenders, but we didn't find any that mimiced Doodle's options. 
**We only have 2 requirements:** 
1) schedule events and 
2) everyone (if possible even without having to register themselves) must be able to sign into an event so it's clear who's attending.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [a lot](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/calendars-a-events/events/events-management) of good extensions that may fit your needs, I can recommend [redEVENT](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/calendars-a-events/events/events-management/6354) 
, here is a [demo](http://app.ohanah.com/demo-v2/rt/)

Comment: thanks! I have been looking in the extensions directory and all over Google. But probably with the wrong keywords. I'll give redEVENT a try.